# Map array to concat shared properties, javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
[
[a, 10],
[b, 20],
[c, 30],
[d, 40],
["err", NaN],
[a, "foo"],
[b, "foo2"],
[c, "foo3"],
[f, "foo4"]
]
```

I want to map the first object of each array, if it's repeated set it like this and if it wasn't shown earlier fill with nulls:

```
[a, 10, "foo"],
[b, 20, "foo2"],
[c, 30, "foo3"],
[d, 40, null ],
[f, null, "foo4"]
```

I'm using lodash but I'm noob.
Any idea how to get closer is really appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems to me [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) will do the job. What are *a*, *b*, etc. Should they be strings, or are they variables?

Comment: It's a bunch of dates , so I don't think .hasOwnProperty() works. I did a patch pushing 0's after the "err", since the first data set had none repeated data but I couldn't figure how to map and compare the first element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using lodash**

Start a lodash's chain. Collect arrays to a group by their 1st index using [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy). Iterate the groups with [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map), init an item that includes the key (0 index), and `null`s. Iterate the group items, and take the 2nd value of the array. Insert the value in the correct place by checking if it's a number ([`_.isNumber`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNumber)):

```js
var arr = [["a",10],["b",20],["c",30],["d",40],["err",null],["a","foo"],["b","foo2"],["c","foo3"],["f","foo4"]];

var result = _(arr) // start a chain
  .groupBy('0') // group by index 0
  .map(function(group, key) { // map the groups
    var item = [key, null, null]; // init an item
    
    // iterate the group
    group.forEach(function(s) {
      item[_.isNumber(s[1]) ? 1 : 2] = s[1]; // add the number or the string to the right place
    });
    
    return item;
  })
  .value(); // get the chain value
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Using ES6**

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array to an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). For each item, check it it exists in the map, and if not, add if not init an item that includes the key (0 index), and `null`s. Place the value in index 1 if it's a number or 2 if it's not. Get the map [values iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) back to an array:

```js
const arr = [["a",10],["b",20],["c",30],["d",40],["err",null],["a","foo"],["b","foo2"],["c","foo3"],["f","foo4"]];

const result = [...arr.reduce((m, [key, value]) => {
  // if item doesn't exist in the Map, create a new item
  m.has(key) || m.set(key, [key, null, null]);
  
  // get the item from the map, and set the new value in the right place
  m.get(key)[typeof value === 'number' ? 1 : 2] = value;
  
  return m;
}, new Map()).values()]; // get the Map's value iterator and spread to an array
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The lowdash option is more code and likely less efficient than an ES5 equivalent using *reduce*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [*Array.prototype.reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). You'll need to get the first element of the array and, if it's the first time you've encountered it, store it in an index along with its position in the result array. Then add a copy of the array to the result array.

If you've seen the index before, just append the value to the result array. E.g.

```js
// First elements are changed to strings for simplicity
var data = [
  ['a', 10],
  ['b', 20],
  ['c', 30],
  ['d', 40],
  ['err', NaN],
  ['a', "foo"],
  ['b', "foo2"],
  ['c', "foo3"],
  ['f', "foo4"]
];

var result = data.reduce(function(acc, arr){

  // Use first element of array as a key. If not seen before, add
  // to index object with its index in the data array.
  // Then append a copy of the data array.
  if (!acc.index.hasOwnProperty(arr[0])) {
    acc.index[arr[0]] = acc.data.length;
    acc.data.push(arr.slice());
    
  // Otherwise, just append the value to appropriate array in data  
  } else {
    acc.data[acc.index[arr[0]]].push(arr[1]);
  }
  
  return acc;

// Required output is in data property
}, {index:{}, data:[]}).data;

console.log(result);
```

I've changed the variables to strings for simplicity. Just make sure that each variable's value is unique when stringified and is suitable as an object property, otherwise you'll need to use a [*Map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

This could be somewhat more concise, at the risk of obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This might do the trick. By any chance do you know if here could be added the nulls on empty spots?